# Invalid JSON RPC response: ""

Tags: node.js, smartcontracts, web3js

I'm trying to set up web3/nodejs on android using telmux(an android/Linux emulator). I'm just trying basic things at the moment.

This is my code to get the balance of an Eth address but I get the error

Invalid JSON RPC response: ""

```
const Web3 = require('web3')                            
const rpcURL= 'http://127.0.0.1:7545' const objWeb3 = new Web3(rpcURL);

async function getBalance(address) {                       
console.log("debug: helpers/getBalance2A");
try {                                                       
return await 
objWeb3.eth.getBalance(address)
} catch (err) {
    console.log("debug: helpers/getBalance2-E error=" + err);
}                                                   }
                                                    
async function demo(){                                                                                      
const address ='0x9658BdD2a5CE0fFd202eF473E033DEE49e28d282';                                                
const balance = await 
getBalance(address);              
console.log(balance);                               
}
                                                    
demo();
```